# CriteriaBuilder with Selection doesn't allow without constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I have a dynamic selection list which I want to execute to get specific columns from the table. But when tried to execute the code, I get the below error.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class
```

```
//Select fields
List<Selection<?>> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer fieldId: fieldIds){
     selectionList.add(recordsVORoot.get("dataAttr"+fieldId));
}
//Final Query
criteriaQuery.multiselect(selectionList).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity class must have a constructor that matches exactly fields of your projection. Order and type of constructor arguments must match sql result.

Comment: Besides having dedicated class tha represent rows and have only required fields? Nothing that I would be aware of.

Comment: If my column names changes dynamically then how I'm suppose to keep a constructor for every combination. Is there a way to achieve something like this where column name changes as received in request?
@Antoniossss and Jeethesh

Comment: You can use Tuples then.

Comment: Can you please share some example for the same? @Antoniossss